# How to solve local changes to file overwritten when pulling after a git update-index --assume-unchanged?

Tags: git

I have a config file storing my local database connection details etc: `application.ini`.

After I initially pulled the project the `application.ini` file is tracked.
So I decided to use:

git update-index --assume-unchanged application.ini

After which I made changes to the file regarding my mysql connection.
All was alright and I am certain that the (tracked) application.ini file on the repo was changed so now when I use:

```
git pull
```

I get:

```
From github.com:username/repo
   669826e..64872d9  master     -> origin/master
Updating ef81735..64872d9
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        application/configs/application.ini
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

git status:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 36 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

git stash save 'application.ini changes':

```
No local changes to save
```

Comment: what if you try to `pull` again? Do you get the same error?

Comment: yes, `git pull` and `git pull -v`

Answer (score 1):

To revert `--assume-unchanged`, which is causing you problems,  use `--no-assume-unchanged`.

Perform this command:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged application.ini
```

Then before doing a `pull`, stash your local changes:

```
$ git stash
```

Do git pull:

```
$ git pull
```

Pop `application.ini` saved changes from stash:

```
$ git stash pop
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, however before the `git stash pop` step I said `git update-index --assume-unchanged application.ini`. Now when I tye `git status` I have (Changes not staged: application.ini)

Comment: Yeah you can do that before or after `stash pop`. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)